# Does Nvidia gpu work in WSL2 from windows 10 home

Tags: drivers, nvidia, windows, windows-subsystem-for-linux, gpu

I want To Know if it is possible to use gpu in WSL2 from windows 10 home 21H2 not insider program my graphics card is old it is Nvidia GeForce gt 520mx is there a way to get it working also I tried [This](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/wsl-user-guide/index.html) 
Article from Nvidia but it want windows 11 or windows 10 insider program so is there another way of doing it like a gpu passthrough or some network protocol?

Comment: eh to do what? there is no graphical display. ALL the hardware is done on the WINDOWS end.

Comment: @Rinzwind machine learning type tasks?

Comment: if what you're looking for is CUDA try https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/enabling-gpu-acceleration-on-ubuntu-on-wsl2-with-the-nvidia-cuda-platform#1-overview

Comment: To be clear: the article from Nvidia is old, the Windows Insider version they mention is 21H1, which is older than your 21H2. Your Windows version should be compatible.

Comment: although, according to the Nvidia site, the driver only supports Pascal and later GPUS (yours is Fermi, which is much older, and therefore not supported and most likely won't work)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The required minimum Windows version for running CUDA in WSL2 is 21H1. At the time the linked Nvidia article was written, that was only available as an Insider preview, but has since been released to the public. Your version of 21H2 is later than the minimum version, so it is definitely fine.

However, the article also says that only Pascal and later GPUs are supported, with Maxwell (predecessor of Pascal) being unsupported, but possibly working. Your GPU is a Fermi GPU, which is a few generations behind Maxwell: definitely unsupported, and quite unlikely to work.